# How to convert json to nested Maps using Gson?

Tags: java, json, gson, pojo

I have a POJO `MyModel.java`:

```
public class MyModel {
  String displayName;
  String id;
  StepDetails stepDetails;
}
```

In `StepDetails.java` I have:

```
public class StepDetails {
  V1 v1;
  V2 v2;
}
```

In `V1.java` and `V2.java`, both are identical with only a Map field `keyValuePairs`:

```
public class V1 {
  Map<String, String> keyValuePairs;
}
```

Example of my json string:

```
{
  "displayName": "My Name",
  "id": "id123",
  "stepDetails": {
    "v1": {
      "key1": "val1",
      "key2": "val2"
    },
    "v2": {
      "key1": "val1",
      "key2": "val2"
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to convert my json string to my model using Gson, the `displayName` and `id` fields in `MyModel` are populated fine, but the maps inside the `v1` and `v2` objects are null. This is what I'm currently doing:

```
MyModel myModel = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, MyModel.class);
```

I've looked at several SO posts but they all seem to suggest using some form of `TypeToken` such as:

```
new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<MyModel>(){}.getType());
```

I tried it but the map fields are still not populated.

Comment: Alternate suggestion, instead of `Map<String, String> keyValuePairs;` you can use `JsonObject keyValuePairs;` I believe this could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `V1` and `V2` types are unnecessary, because in the JSON, the dictionaries you want are directly associated with the keys "v1" and "v2". Therefore, the types of the fields `v1` and `v2` should be `Map<String, String>`:

```
class MyModel {
    private String displayName;
    private String id;
    private StepDetails stepDetails;

    // getters...
}

class StepDetails {
    private Map<String, String> v1;
    private Map<String, String> v2;

    // getters...
}
```